# sql complex tree rows

Tags: mysql, sql, treeview

i have following function with a query. it works fine with integer id, but if the id is varchar (ID: Xewi3adc), then it dont work. well i dont know how to make it work yet, i been making lots of modifications, but i could'nt get it work.

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS album_tree_connect;

DELIMITER $$

CREATE FUNCTION album_tree_connect(value varchar(32)) RETURNS INT
NOT DETERMINISTIC
READS SQL DATA
BEGIN
    DECLARE _id varchar(32);
    DECLARE _parent varchar(32);
    DECLARE _next INT;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET @id = NULL;

    SET _parent = @id;
    SET _id = -1;

    IF @id IS NULL THEN
        RETURN NULL;
    END IF;

    LOOP
        SELECT  MIN(album_id)
        INTO    @id
        FROM    album
        WHERE   sub_album_of_album_id = _parent
            AND album_id > _id;
        IF @id IS NOT NULL OR _parent = @start_with THEN
            SET @level = @level + 1;
            RETURN @id;
        END IF;
        SET @level := @level - 1;
        SELECT  album_id, sub_album_of_album_id
        INTO    _id, _parent
        FROM    album
        WHERE   album_id = _parent;
    END LOOP;   
END
$$

DELIMITER ;


## select statement to pull the tree menu

SELECT   CONCAT(REPEAT('    ', level - 1), CAST(hi.album_id AS CHAR)) AS treeitem, sub_album_of_album_id, name, user_id, level
FROM    (
        SELECT  album_tree_connect(album_id) AS id, @level AS level
        FROM    (
                SELECT  @start_with := 0,
                        @id := @start_with,
                        @level := 0
                ) vars, album
        WHERE   @id IS NOT NULL
        ) ho
JOIN    album hi
ON      hi.album_id = ho.id
where user_id = 2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function return type is declared as INT, so the return value will be coerced to that type.  If the value to be returned (the album_id field) is not an integer, it may get mangled.
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-procedure.html

Comment: i tried.. but didnt work sadly.. can you try it and tell me please.. i can give you quick sql dump, if you want.

Answer (score 1):

First, fix your function declaration as `GApple` suggested:

```
CREATE FUNCTION album_tree_connect(value varchar(32)) RETURNS VARCHAR(32)
```

Second, the initial `_id` should be initialized to an emtpy string , not `-1`:

```
SET _id = '';
```

Third, your `@start_with` should also be initialized with a string (the one that serves as a parent node identifier):

```
SELECT   CONCAT(REPEAT('    ', level - 1),
         CAST(hi.album_id AS CHAR)) AS treeitem, sub_album_of_album_id, name, user_id, level
FROM    (
        SELECT  album_tree_connect(album_id) AS id, @level AS level
        FROM    (
                SELECT  @start_with := '0',

                        --- The '0' above should be a string.

                        @id := @start_with,
                        @level := 0
                ) vars, album
        WHERE   @id IS NOT NULL
        ) ho
JOIN    album hi
ON      hi.album_id = ho.id
```

Note that the filter on `user_id` in the query above will most probably work incorrectly.

You need either to wrap the function into a subquery:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (
        SELECT   CONCAT(REPEAT('    ', level - 1),
                 CAST(hi.album_id AS CHAR)) AS treeitem, sub_album_of_album_id, name, user_id, level
        FROM    (
                SELECT  album_tree_connect(album_id) AS id, @level AS level
                FROM    (
                        SELECT  @start_with := '0',

                                --- The '0' above should be a string.

                                @id := @start_with,
                                @level := 0
                        ) vars, album
                WHERE   @id IS NOT NULL
                ) ho
        JOIN    album hi
        ON      hi.album_id = ho.id
        ) q
WHERE   user_id = 2
```

or modify the hierarchical function to take the filter into account.